# Make a custom Ubuntu 20.04 usb boot thumb drive

Tags: live-usb

My Main Goal:

I am looking to create a custom ubuntu usb boot thumb drive (fat32) that is very slimmed down and boot directly into one GUI application automatically.

EDIT: Specifically I'm looking to update this old abandoned project [Amilator](https://www.generationamiga.com/2017/09/24/amilator-v4-9-1-released-start-any-amigaos-from-a-usb-stick/) which runs FS-UAE emulator from bootable USB. It was based on Debian x86 and I wish to rebuild it using Ubuntu amd64.

EDIT 2: Thank you for comments. I will check out Cubic and Puppy Linux (Did surprise me this one as I thought Puppy Linux wasn't Ubuntu base but see there are many versions now) and I'll write back on how it goes.

I'm trying to base it off Ubuntu 20.04.

I have been following guides that use `debootstrap` [found here](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/)

I replace:

```
sudo debootstrap \
    --arch=i386 \
    --variant=minbase \
    stretch \
    $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot \
    http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/
```

With:

```
sudo debootstrap \
    --arch=amd64 \
    focal \
    ~/LIVE_BOOT/chroot \
    http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

I get stuck at the following stage:

```
cp $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/boot/initrd.img-* \
    $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/image/initrd
```

initrd.img-* does not exist or any file like it. On further research I've learnt that Ubuntu doesn't use mkinitrd but mkinitramfs.

Do I need to start from scratch and use another tool instead of `debootstrap` which is better for Ubuntu or is there something I'm missing to get this working.

All my research so far on this subject only brings up out of date ubuntu releases and debootstrap.

Comment: Seems like you might be re-inventing some form of [kiosk](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk).

Comment: Does [Cubic](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic/) work for you ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: A Ubuntu Minimal install is about 3.5GB. A Puppy Linux install starts at less than 256MB. Puppy comes with the bootable ISO creator "Remaster Puppy Live CD" built in. Puppy runs in RAM and is fast.